# ReactJS tutorial: does not display the expected unique key warning

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to ReactJS and I'm trying to follow the tutorial here: https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html . Everything seems fine except at this step: https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html#picking-a-key where it says

> For now, we should see a list of the moves that have occurred in the game and a warning that says:
>
> > Warning: Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique “key” prop. Check the render method of “Game”.

I've set up my project using create-react-app (following the instructions here: https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html#setup-option-2-local-development-environment), did not change any settings, yet for some reason at this step (before a key is added to the li element) when I run "npm start", I don't see the said warning.

I've tried googling for the answer, ironically all the results I've found are people asking how to get rid of this warning, whereas I'm trying to see this warning. Does anyone know what could be happening here?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where do you look for this warning? If you are not looking developer console then you can't see it.

Comment: can you include your code so we can help you

Comment: @devserkan thank you so much! It's ridiculous how the simplest things can trip up beginners... the example in the tutorial (codepen.io/gaearon/pen/EmmGEa?editors=0010) showed the warning on the webpage itself, so I assumed I’d also see it there. Would you like to post an answer so I can accept it and close this question?

Comment: No problem, in 2018 everything is ridiculously difficult for beginners to start web developing :) I'm in the same boat. I've provided an answer but it was difficult to give an answer for such a small issue :)

Comment: Thanks, though in this case the tutorial could've made it clear that the error was expected in the console, and that they only overwrote console.log in their codepen snippet to make it more obvious for beginners (but unfortunately had the opposite effect!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a warning coming from React side and you can see it in your **browser's developer tool's console** as an **error**. I know it is weird but I think people turn off the warnings and since keys are necessary for React to handle the list items in a stable way, it is shown as an error.